# Test for significant differences on gender between two groups in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I need to compare the significance of Gender between the two groups.
Here is the table:

```
df <- data.frame(No = c(1:15),
                 Group = sample(1:2, 15, replace=T),
                 Gender = sample(c("F","M"), 15, replace=T))


Ge_M <- df %>%
  filter(Gender == "M") %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Value = n()) %>%
  pull(Value)

Ge_F <- df %>%
  filter(Gender == "F") %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Value = n()) %>%
  pull(Value)

t.test(Ge_M, Ge_F)
```

Output :

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Ge_M and Ge_F
t = -0.82199, df = 1.0555, p-value = 0.5561
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -36.65746  31.65746
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      2.5       5.0
```

Question:
Am I using it in the right way? I want to know if I have significant a difference between the two groups but the output seems not what I want.

What's the right method to do the test?

Thank you!

Comment: Using your code it works for me,  
`data: Value and Group  
F = 2.6127, num df = 1, denom df = 18, p-value = 0.1234.`

Comment: You have many zeros in your data. What is the explanation for them? Looking at the data I have doubts that the assumptions of a t-test are sufficenctly fulfilled.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to the current version**

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do here since the new `df` misses the response (see below). But one critique may be that you may want to check for the homoscedasticity assumption first, using say `var.test` or any other test for equality of variances. And if the homoscedasticity assumption cannot be rejected, then you can use a t-test with `var.equal = TRUE`.

**Answer to the original version of the post**

The problem here is with the use of *`df`* which is an `R` function (`df` computes the density of an F distribution, run `?df` to check it). Using another name, say `dd`, fixes the issue. Note that in the case of two groups, you can also use the $t$-test.

```
dd <- read.table("data.txt", header = F,row.names = 1)
names(dd) <- c("ID", "group", "value")
str(dd)

 > oneway.test(value ~ group, data = dd, var.equal = TRUE)

    One-way analysis of means

data:  value and group
F = 2.6127, num df = 1, denom df = 18, p-value = 0.1234

# or the equivalent version via t-test
 > with(dd, t.test(value~group, var.equal = TRUE))

    Two Sample t-test

data:  value by group
t = -1.6164, df = 18, p-value = 0.1234
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and group 2 is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.580329  1.118425
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       2.385714        6.116667
```

**Remark** Furthermore, as also highlighted in the comments by [Roland](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11849/roland), `value` under group 1 has many zeros, i.e.

```
> with(dd, table(value[group == 1]))

   0    2  4.3  6.6  8.3 12.2 
   9    1    1    1    1    1
```

This casts doubts on the normality of such a variable and thus the p-value of the t-test (or ANOVA) may not be correct.